# Form has minimum size after restoring from minimize state

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, binding, size

I Added ClientSize to Application Settings and DataBindings in Properties window, in order to save size of the form after it was closed. And that worked. But when I minimize form and then activate it back, it has minimum size . Is it a bug or I'm doing something wrong

1. Create New Project (WindowForm Application)
2. Open Properties Window form Form1
3. In Application Settings choose PropertyBinding
4. Add Binding for Location and ClientSize
5. Run
6. Maximize and then Restore

Comment: Yeesh. You're right, that's ugly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found answer in this [topic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rprabhu/archive/2005/11/28/497792.aspx). So to save size and location without side effects , need to remove binding and save application settings by hand

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   Properties.Settings.Default.Size = this.Size;
   Properties.Settings.Default.Location = this.Location;
   Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.Size = Properties.Settings.Default.Size;
   this.Location = Properties.Settings.Default.Location;
}
```

Comment: That still doesn't solve the problem.  You do *not* want to save the Size/Location when the WindowState isn't Normal.

Comment: @Hans Passant - In my situation form can be only minimized, So no need to check if form is maximized and restore it's size

Comment: Well, it is just as cheap to write this code universally correct as it is to make it only work in your specific case.

Comment: @Hans Passant In the link I provided , there is solution that works with maximized form. Here I posted code that works for my situation

Answer (score 0):

Bad combinations of docking, filling and autosize between the form, controls and sub-controls can have that effect.

Comment: Tried that on new form without controls and docking style. Behaviour is same

Comment: @Stecya - if you have a way of reproducing this issue, can you edit your question and document the steps to reproduce it? It'll make things a lot easier for others to diagnose (start with the step "New Project...", and document every step)